# Calculation of days till some date in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["25.01.2020"]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"], format = "%d%m%Y")
```

And I have special dates like below:

```
special_date = pd.to_datetime(["20.01.2020", "01.02.2020"], dayfirst=True)
```

ANd I need to calculate 2 columns in this DataFrame:

- col1 = number of days to the next special date
- col2 = number of days from the last special date

So I need result like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could vectorise this to make it much faster
2. My numbers are off by 1 from your example. I'm calculating "how many days between 00:00:00 on row.data to 00:00:00 on the next/previous special day". adjust accordingly if you want to calculate from the end of the day - really just add or subtract 1.
3. You'll thank yourself later if you switch to more descriptive column names (I hope these were just for the example)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["25.01.2020", "24.01.2020"]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"], format = "%d.%m.%Y")
special_date = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["20.01.2020", "01.02.2020"], dayfirst=True))

col1 = []
col2 = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    # TODO: Handle if there is no next/previous special date

    next_special_date = special_date[special_date >= row.data].iloc[0]
    col1.append((next_special_date - row.data)/pd.Timedelta('1D'))

    previous_special_date = special_date[special_date <= row.data].iloc[-1]
    col2.append((row.data - previous_special_date)/pd.Timedelta('1D'))

df["col1"] = col1
df["col2"] = col2

print(df)
```

```
        data  col1  col2
0 2020-01-25   7.0   5.0
1 2020-01-24   8.0   4.0
```